# Filtering values and sum in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

Hi Please help me on my below questions. totally upset with this!

I have 3 columns Agency, Amount and Year

I want to group the data by Agency and sum those values

for example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoql0.png)

and I need answer like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkALR.png)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select agency,
    sum(case when year = 2018 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2018,
    sum(case when year = 2019 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2019
from mytable
where year in (2018, 2019)
group by agency
```